# ember.js, Is it possible to access to the template from the controler?

Tags: jquery, ember.js

I am really new in emberjs but i really want to learn more about it. I am building a webapp with ember.

So, the question is as follows. I have a page (users), that should display all of the objects users, defined in models/users.js . While iam loading the user object from my rest api i want to diplay 'processing..' (I use jquery blockui) at the user block (div id= users-id). I dont know if i can do it on the userRoute. or should i put it somewhere else?

```
    ==my users.hbs
<div id="users-id" class="jumbotron">
    <ul class="users-listing">
        {{#each user in model}}
        <li>{{user.name}} - {{user.email}}</li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</div>

    ==usersRoute.js
        App.UsersRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
        setupController: function(controller){
      $('#users-id').block({ 
         message: 'processing...'});
      $.getJSON('.../users').then(function(data){
         Ember.run(function() {
            controller.set('model', data.body);
         });              
      });
      $('#users-id').unblock();
   }  
    });

    ==usersController.js
    App.UsersController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
       sortProperties: ['name'],
       sortAscending: true // false = descending
    });

    ==user.js (model)
    App.User = DS.Model.extend({
        name         : DS.attr(),
        email        : DS.attr()
    });

    ==store
    App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter;
    App.store = DS.Store.extend()

    ==router
    App.Router.map(function(){
        this.resource('users', function(){
            this.resource('user', { path:'/:user_id' }, function(){
                this.route('edit');
            });
            this.route('create');
        });
    });
```

I dont know if it is possible to do that..
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you'll probably be interested in 1 of 2 solutions.

1. The new loading routes: https://gist.github.com/machty/6944577 (http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/proposal-nested-loading-routes/2895)
2. A global loading div element that lives outside of your ember app, that you can manipulate during the model/setupController stages

The problem with your current approach is the template for that route isn't injected until after model/setupController are resolved